# Android Auto Tab to next EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-filter

How do you set editText that are created dynamically to auto tab to the next one when you use a InputFilter to limit the number of characters? (created inside a for loop)

```
        editTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        editTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        editTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        editTextView.setHighlightColor(Color.GRAY);
        InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2); //Filter to 10 characters
        editTextView.setFilters(filters);
        editTextView.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the InputFilter crosses the limit for the number of characters add this

```
editTextView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, however it does not appear to go to the next editText field.  Do I have to set tags or something to let it know what field is next?